# How can I get a list of MaaS nodes that all have a specific tag from maas the CLI?

Tags: maas

The [documentation for MaaS](https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/man/maas.8.html) states:

```
Filter the list using specific key/value pairs:

    $ maas maas nodes list architecture="i386/generic"
```

This seems to suggest that I could do something like this:

```
$ maas maas nodes list tag_names="Blue"
```

To get all the nodes that are tagged with the "Blue" tag. But this doesn't seem to work. In fact, no matter what I put after the list parameter the maas server seems to return all the nodes. Is there a way to limit the nosed returned as it stated in the documentation? Or is there a better way to have the maas server only return a subset of nodes that match a specific value?